# Adding columns to a csv table with AWK from multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

I'm looking to build a csv table by getting values from several files with AWK. I have it working with two files, but I can't scale it beyond that. I'm currently taking the output of the second file, and appending the third, and so on.

Here are example files:

```
#file1  #file2  #file3  #file4
100     45      1       5
200     23      1       2
300     29      2       1
400     0       1       2
500     74      4       5
```

This is the goal:

```
#data.csv
1,100,45,1,5
2,200,23,1,2
3,300,29,2,1
4,400,0,1,2
5,500,74,4,5
```

This is what I have working:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = NR", " $0","; next } { print a[FNR""], $0}' $file1 $file2
```

With the result:

```
1, 100, 45
2, 200, 23
3, 300, 29
4, 400, 0
5, 500, 74
```

But when I try and get it to work on 3 or more files, like so:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = NR", " $0","; next } { print a[FNR""], $0; next } { print a[FNR""], $0}' $file1 $file2 $file3
```

I get this output:

```
1, 100, 45
2, 200, 23
3, 300, 29
4, 400, 0
5, 500, 74
1, 100, 1 
2, 200, 1 
3, 300, 2
4, 400, 1
5, 500, 4
```

In the first column the line count restarts, and the second column it also repeats the first file. In the third column is where it adds the third and subsequent files as new rows, where I would expect these should be added as columns. No new rows required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have learned most of my AWK from Stack Exchange, and I know I'm missing something fundamental here. Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

as already answered you can use `paste`. To get the exact output with comma delimited line numbering, you can do this

```
paste -d, file{1..4} | nl -s, -w1
```

- `-s,` sets number separator as comma (default is tab).
- `-w1` sets number width, so there are no initial spaces (because default is bigger)

---

another solution with `awk`

```
awk    '{a[FNR]=a[FNR] "," $0} 
    END {for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) print i a[i]}' file{1..4}
```

Comment: Both of these are great solutions. Use this.

Comment: One note for distinction between `{1..4}` vs `[1-4]`; the former will complain if any of the files is missing, the latter will do with whatever is there.

Comment: @thanasisp these are both great! I wasn't aware of the paste command.

Comment: The `-s,` flag gives it the line numbers, but only single digits. Cycling back to 0 after 9. If I use `-s` it gives me the line numbers correctly but adds the other flag.

`8,477,3461
9,3474,6100
0,471,6602
1,3662,3628`

And the Awk example is great too. However, is there a way to get the lines sorted correctly? They are numbered right, but the rows get muddled. See example below of the first 5 rows of a 23 row table.

`22,485,6871,6183,465,3954
2,458,3178,2621,477,707
23,951,5063,3163,476,707
3,454,4128,2323,462,1009
4,454,3715,2873,447,666`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use paste and then simply number each row:-

```
paste -d"," file1 file2 file3 file4
100,45,1,5
200,23,1,2
300,29,2,1
400,0 ,1,2
500,74,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution for a variable number of files:

```
awk '{ !line[FNR] && line[FNR]=FNR; line[FNR]=line[FNR]","$0 }
     END { for (i=1; i<=length(line); i++) print line[i] }' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

For example:

```
$ awk '{ !line[FNR] && line[FNR]=FNR; line[FNR]=line[FNR]","$0 }
      END { for (i=1; i<=length(line); i++) print line[i] }' \
      <(seq 1 5) <(seq 11 15) <(seq 21 25) <(seq 31 35)
1,1,11,21,31
2,2,12,22,32
3,3,13,23,33
4,4,14,24,34
5,5,15,25,35
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a beginner friendly solution. If you need to manipulate the data on the way in you can clearly see which file is being read.
 
ARGIND is `gawk` specific. It tells us which file we are processing.  We fill two arrays `a` and `b` from `file1` and `file2` and then print your desired output while processing file3.

```
awk '
ARGIND == 1 { a[FNR] = $0 ; next }
ARGIND == 2 { b[FNR] = $0 ; next }
ARGIND == 3 { print FNR "," a[FNR] "," b[FNR] "," $0 }
' file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
1,100,45,1
2,200,23,1
3,300,29,2
4,400,0,1
5,500,74,4
```