# How to call 2 macro in jinja2 at a same line?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 to generate a txt file (not html). I have created a macro which generates a tab spaced table. For example,

```
col1   col2
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d
```

I want to generate 2 tables side by side. Something like below,

```
col1   col2                 col_1   col2
1      a                    9       d
2      b                    8       e
3      c                    7       f
4      d
```

I tried below syntax but it is not producing intended result. It is creating table2 in next line

```
{{print_table(1)}}         {{print_table(2)}}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Note: My table construction is complex and here I gave a simple example.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a simple builtin Jinja2 function. The best approach IMO to modify the `print_table()` to support multiple tables at once.

Comment: I was afraid that it is the only option :(

Comment: You can also create two txt files, then with a Linux [oneliner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399107/5451046) create the desired file in a `subprocess` call.